# How do you change the loading image in visual composer on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loading, visual-composer

I have visual composer running in wordpress.  When media grids load, there is a loading graphic.  My client hates the default graphic and wants me to create a custom one.  I can not find where this is controlled in the code, nor can I even figure out what the name of the graphic is to swop it out.

the page is:  http://ninawilliamsinteriors.com/index.php/portfolio/rooms/living_rooms/

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one: http://ninawilliamsinteriors.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/loadingspinner150.gif

You could upload a different image with the same file name in the same folder and replace this one. This should make the change. There is probably a cleaner solutions via the admin panel though. Try to find it first.

I managed to see this URL using the inspect feature of Google Chrome in the Network tab. There is a list with the loaded assets there you can use in the future.

If this is not the one you are talking about, I see something else showing under it. It looks like gray circles to me. Might be made entirely with CSS and without an image.